# SQL error, Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
declare @StartDate varchar(30), @myStartDate date, @iterate int, @DaysDiff int, @NoOfDays varchar (200) , @username varchar(30), @StaffID int
select @DaysDiff = 6, @iterate =0, @StartDate = '2015-04-29', @username = 'itdsnm'
select @StaffID = StaffID from Staff where LoginName = @username
select @myStartDate = cast(@StartDate as DATE) 
begin
Create Table #Temp8(Dates date,MyDay int)
    While @iterate < @DaysDiff +1
    Begin
        Insert Into #Temp8(Dates,MyDay)
        Select @myStartDate,DATEPART(dw,@myStartDate)
        Select @myStartDate = dateadd(dd,1,@myStartDate) 
        IF (Select COUNT(*) from #Temp8 where Dates In(Select StartDate From Holidays Where Username = @StaffID )) >0
        Begin 
            Select @NoOfDays = 'One of your days fall between a holiday already taken, please review'
            Return
        End
        Else
            Select @iterate = @iterate + 1
        End
;With Temp2(Dates,MyDay)
As
(Select Dates,MyDay from #Temp8 Where MyDay not in (1,7))

Select @NoOfDays = COUNT(*) from Temp2 Where Dates Not In (Select Date From BankHolidays)
   end
```

Everything works fine in the above procedure, but when it comes to the With statement, it throws me an error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." Can Some one help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms? (This is product specific functionality...)

Comment: please show a sample of the data and schema with data types of `BankHolidays`

Comment: Bank Holidays is a table creates in SQL manually with dates of holidays eg:2015-05-25,2015-08-31,2015-12-25 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Tanner that the schema is required to be able to assess the issue (i.e. the column datatypes).

At first glance, though it appears to me that perhaps `[Date]` in `[BankHolidays]` is some sort of string datatype and that column contains certain string values that cannot be converted to a `DATE` type.

Comment: Hi Goody thank you so much. Ya the Date in BankHoliday was declared as varchar and also there is a mismatch of Date format. Thanks once again